# Ruby - Return A Proc.Call As Variable?

Tags: ruby, scope, proc

I'm trying to create a Ruby method that:
1. accepts as input a proc which accepts *two* arguments and
2. returns as output a proc which takes *one* argument (the other argument being passed in with the first proc.)

Code below. Everything I've read about how Ruby handles functional scope indicates that I *should* be able to return a proc.call as a variable, and I don't understand why I'm getting an "unexpected return" error (reproduced below the code)

(I'm obviously a beginning Rubyist...my experience has mostly been in JavaScript, where the mechanics of doing this sort of thing are, I think, much more intuitive.)

--

```
def partial (proc1, val1)
  return Proc.new {|val2| return proc1.call(val1,val2)}
end

adder = Proc.new {|a,b| a + b}

sum_five = partial(adder,5)

sum_five.call(10) # -- expecting 15

# unexpected return
# (repl):13:in `block in partial'
# (repl):20:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2):

In Ruby, procs and lambdas treat return differently.

Procs are designed to work within other Ruby control structures, so in that context a return is from the control structure. Lambdas are much more like stand-alone methods, so return returns from the lambda. You get an error because the proc has no context to return from.

Try this:

```
def partial (proc1, val1)
  return lambda {|val2| return proc1.call(val1,val2)}
end

adder = Proc.new {|a,b| a + b}

sum_five = partial(adder,5)

puts sum_five.call(10) # -- expecting 15
```

Comment: By the way, all the return statements in this example are superfluous and can be deleted without changing the meaning of the code.

Comment: That works...Thanks! From your comment and other sources, I'm getting the sense that lambdas are closer than procs are to JavaScript functions (which can be passed around with less concern for scope).

Answer (score 0):

Shorter/cleaner ruby syntax:

```
def composer(proc1, val1)
  -> (val2) { proc1.call(val1, val2) }
end

adder = -> (a,b) { a + b }

sum_five = composer(adder, 5)

sum_five.call(10)
```

Comment: This is the syntax for a *lambda literal*, not a proc.

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't understand it's name, Ruby already has a method, [`Proc#curry`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Proc.html#method-i-curry), that does this:

```
adder = Proc.new {|a,b| a + b}
sum_five = adder.curry.call(5)
sum_five.call(10) # => 15
sum_five.call(2) # => 7
```

just watch out, because `curry` takes an optional argument, which is the number of arguments it should expect before `call`ing the initial proc, so if you pass it the argument you want as the "default" it'll work weird:

```
adder = Proc.new {|a,b| a + b}
sum_five = adder.curry(5) # NOTE: This is incorrect
sum_five.call(1) # => returns a Proc
sum_five[1][2][3][4][5] # => 3 (the first 2 arguments got passed, the rest ignored)
```